# Why does opening a form takes longer the first time?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, user-interface

I have made a simple search utility that will search for files in your computer.
 It has a function `search` which searches for the files and creates the  list of matched items to a `mainloop` function which in turn calls  `displayForm` function which displays the results of the search in a new form.
  Whenever, I run the application the first time after startup, although the `search` function completes the search in about 1 seconds, the time taken to display the result window takes considerable time(about 10 seconds) . This happens only for the first time you search after startup.

I am not providing any code for `search` function because I don't think `search` function matters because It takes almost same amount of time irrespective of running it the first time or subsequent times, and the working of `displayForm` is very simple.

```
    public void displayForm()
    {
        // Do some stuff here 
        // Make a listbox and add items to display. 
        SearchForm.ShowDialog() ;  
    }
```

Also, by experimenting with a few cases , I must tell you that  making  a list box takes the same time irrespective of running it first time or subsequent times.
What could be the possible reasons for this ?

Comment: How many items are we talking about?

Comment: running anything the first time requires everything to be JIT'd and loaded in memory. Thereafter subsequent requests are much faster as its there, ready to be used. That's normal. To make it faster, perhaps compile your app down to using NGen which makes it native so you don't necessarily, I guess, invoke or use any of the .NET runtime features and environment. There can be various factors why it takes long in your scenario - could be your GPU rendering, could be the control you are using, could be... goodness knows what else.

Comment: @LarsTech It takes longer for the first time, after that it works as expected.

Comment: Show us the code in your `displayForm`.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the problem has occured with 1 item as well as 100 items

Comment: I am not searching for files using the conventional method by recursively searching each and every directory.  I have maintained my own index of the files and in the `search` function , I am just reading that index(files).

Comment: And also, if the problem is with the `search` function, why does it occur only the first time.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks , that's the kind of info I was looking for!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is entirely normal, it has little to do with your code.  Cold start time is dominated by the speed of the hard disk.  Which can be disappointing when it has to locate the many DLLs that are required to start a .NET app.  Not a problem exclusive to .NET apps, large unmanaged apps like Office apps and Adobe Reader have this issue as well.  Which tend to cheat by installing an "optimizer", a program that runs at login and makes your machine slow by pre-loading the DLLs that the program needs so they are available in the file system cache, defeating SuperFetch in the process.

The operating system's file system cache is a pretty effective solution for the slow disk, but it is like a mile long freight train to get up to speed.  Getting it filled from scratch with useful data takes a while, effective disk transfer rates when it has to seek is at best a few megabytes/sec.  Also the core reason that users like an SSD so much, it provides a much more fundamental solution.  Once you've experienced one, you can never go back.

Covered very well in many excellent articles, best way to find them is by googling ".NET cold start time".